# Validating Prediction Understanding & Approach

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Given the following question is the understanding and approach in the solution valid/sound?

**Question**

1. A defect occurs at a rate of 20%
2. For all defective products, an algorithm accurately predicts a defect at a rate of 90%
3. For products that *are not* defective the algorithm erroneously predicts a defect at a rate of 15%

For a random product, what is the probability that the algorithm predicts it will be defective?

**Solution**

$$ P(True\ Positive) = 0.9 * 0.2 = 0.18\\
P(False\ Positive) = 0.15 * 0.8 = 0.12\\
P(Predict Defect)\\
= P(True\ Positive) + P(False\ Positive) - P(True\ Positive \cap False\ Positive)\\
= 0.18 + 0.12 - 0 = 0.30
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A=\{\text{defective product}\}\\
B=\{\text{defective prediction}\}$

$P(A)=0.2\\
P(B|A)=0.9\\
P(B|A^c)=0.15$

$P(B)=?$

Using the law of total probability

$P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)+P(B|A^c)P(A^c)=\dots$